# What rewards do you get for skill points?

Tags: achievements, resistance-fall-of-man

Skill points and the acquisition of such are basically the ingame achievement system in *Resistance: Fall of Man*. According to the ingame system, I unlock Rewards at 10, 20, 40, 70, 100, and 126 points. However, I can't see what they are, as they're all behind strings of question marks.

Are there any gameplay advantages in the rewards, such as new weapons, or are they just extra like concept art or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found several lists of the unlocks, but few details on what they all do.  Some of them are fairly clear, though:

- 10 points: Concept Art Pack 1
- 20 points: Concept Art Pack 2
- 40 points: Unlock Wrench for Allies
- 70 points: Flip levels
- 100 points: Clank Backpacks
- 126 points: Multiplayer Mechanic Skin

"Clank" likely refers to [Clank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clank_%28Ratchet_&_Clank%29) from Ratchet & Clank, since it's the same studio's game.  (They appear to be [for decoration only](http://ratchet.wikia.com/wiki/Clank_Backpack).)  The "Wrench" is also likely a R&C nod, as that's Ratchet's primary weapon in the series.  ([This page](http://iriscompendium.wikia.com/wiki/Mighty_Wrench) has a picture of someone with the wrench on, although it's the multiplayer unlock version)

Flip levels is the real mystery here, the only info I could find was that the levels are "[mirrored](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/928399-resistance-fall-of-man/48531048)," which seems like a simple graphical change rather than anything significant that would extend the life of the game.

Comment: Are the Clank backpacks for multiplayer only, or will you also see other soldiers running around with them on in single player?

Comment: I believe they are multiplayer-only, [Wikipedia states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratchet_%26_Clank): "Clank, along with Ratchet's Omniwrench and Gravity boots, appear as unlockable bangles for soldiers to use in online multiplayer."

Comment: Clank backpacks appear in single player too on friendly soldiers. It's cosmetic only

Comment: @JohnoBoy, what about the wrenches?  There's also some other R&C goodies for multiplayer milestones, do those apply as well?

Comment: I really can't remember, I haven't played the game's multiplayer that much and only toggled the Clank backpacks once to check it out.